# NE555 is heating

Tags: power-supply, 555, switching

I have this 2 circuit and my 555 ic is heating up

1.) Switch circuit(momentary button toggle as on/off using 555 timer)
2.) Voltage regulator circuit(where sensors, lcd and esp8266 nodemcu is connected)

In switch circuit, when the momentary button is pressed, it allows the voltage from my "12v 2A DC Adaptor" to flow to the voltage regulator circuit.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you go read the 555 data sheet.  Output can source or sink 200mA.  It's not meant to drive a circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Ne555 is heating up, becouse You are using it's high side output transisor to pass power for rest of Your project. Esp8266 consumes quite a lot of power (whe n wifi enabled), lcd (probably with backlight) also eats current. This transistor inside Ne555 is bipolar, and has significant voltage drop across it - thus it's heating up. This is not the best approach to do it (energy inefficient). Simplest solution would be to add PMOS high-side switch and drive it from Ne555. It will have very small Rdson, so very little power will be dissipated.

**Example solution:**

[image]

Rest of the circuit is the same. Chosen somponents are not critical, almost any PMOS with enough D-S voltage and D current is ok, any bipolar npn is ok. Also D1 is not exactly needed.

Comment: May I see your example schematic please. Thanks

Comment: Why R3 if I may ask?

Comment: When npn is driven hard, it will limit peak current through it, which could be large if mosfet with high miller capactiance (possibly in high voltage application) is used. Also - when Mosfet get's damaged (all leads shorted) npn will be proctected - when R3 would be 0 - npn will possibly short power supply and burn itself down.